# Can I registed properties to only one object in blender?

Tags: python, scripting

I knew that registering properties is done by:

```
bpy.types.Object.my_data = PointerProperty(type=my_props)
```

The problem is that this registers the properties to all objects, I want them for only one object (the selected object for example). Is that possible?

Comment: Custom props for ID objects eg   `context.object["prop"] = 33` for basic types like string float and int, but not for pointers as demonstrated in question... are only defined on a per object instance basis.